# Store information on version of external programs at the commit date?

Tags: git, dependencies

While stumbling over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460022/preferred-version-control-methodology/460199#460199) old thread, I noticed there is one thing I didn't worry about so far: external dependencies. Is there a smart<sup>1</sup> way to make git store some basic information on the current version of external applications used?

<sup>1)</sup> with smart I mean something more sophisticated than keeping manually track in a textfile everytime I remember having done such an update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, IDE's will keep track of required external dependencies + version information for you (in the form of workspace and project files).

If that is not enough for you, you could have a look at git submodules which allows you to 'refer' to specific versions of external projects (which could be in git, svn, bzr or hg repositories through the use of git-svn, git-hg and so on)

Comment: Sorry I only now came around to accept/upvote your answer, I totally missed its presence until now...